# Python scraping Error MissingSchema: Invalid URL

Tags: python, url

Does anybody know why a get this error ?

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/type/gymnasien/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///type/gymnasien/?
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list, _r = [0, 10]):
for i in range(*_r):
 new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
 if new_d:
   yield new_d[-1]['title']

d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/').text,   'html.parser')
results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
print(list(get_emails(results)))
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. What links do you have contained in `_links`? Most likely one of them is `/type/gymnasien/`, but what you probably meant to do is append `/type/gymnasien/` to the base URL of `http://www.schulliste.eu`. I suspect if you wrote `requests.get("http://www.schulliste.eu" + _links[i])` it would resolve that exception.

Comment: @Mihai Chelaru "  _links is not defined" is the error I get if i try your suggestion Did you mean that: 
    d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu' + _links[i]).text, 'html.parser')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand from your code, you're looking to scrape links to a bunch of schools, then use the `get_emails()` function to follow those links and scrape the school contact emails. If you look inside the `results` list that you pass to `get_emails()`, you will see that it contains some relative links internal to the site that `requests` does not know how to handle:

```
>>> print(results[1])
/type/gymnasien/
```

These links might not be the ones you want to even follow, so what you can do is try and remove them from the list of scraped links before you pass them to your `get_emails()` function:

```
results_filtered = [link for link in results if link.startswith('http://')]
```

Then you can use those results downstream and `get_emails()` should no longer complain about `MissingSchema`. The final code would look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list, _r = [0, 10]):
    for i in range(*_r):
     new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
     if new_d:
       yield new_d[-1]['title']

d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/').text, 'html.parser')
results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
results = [link for link in results if link.startswith('http://')]
print(list(get_emails(results)))
```

Which prints the following output:

```
['schule@waldorfschulemarburg.de', 'e-gym@schulen-ee.de', 'martina.kock@louisenlund.de', 'gymnasium.sn@ecolea.de', 'admissions@dresden-is.de', 'info@sankt-matthias.de', 'info@marienhoehe.de', 'kubera@ams-viernheim.de', 'gymnasium.hro@ecolea.de']
```

Comment: oh yes now I understand and it works as well. Thanks so much. Do I have to remove _r=[0,10] to get all email adresses?

Comment: No it doesnt :( NameError: name '_r' is not defined. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh sorry, if you remove that argument, then you can't use it in `for i in range(*_r):`, so you will have to instead iterate over the `_links` list, either by going `for i in range(len(_links)):` or iterating over links itself in the for loop with `for link in _links:` and then replacing `requests.get(_links[i])` with `requests.get(link)`.

Comment: many thanks, now it works :) But this code does just scrap the email addresses from this site and dont step to the next site right ( you have to press a continue button to get to the the next site, each side shows just 20 results, there are 2400 results all in all)? Is there a way to fix this with python ? Or do I have to scrap email adresses site by site?

Comment: Generally it's frowned upon to ask too many questions in a single post. It's best to create a separate question when you have something new to think about. On this particular site you'll notice there are next and back buttons, and if you click to get to the next page there's a parameter passed to the URL that gives the next 20 results `?bundesland=&start=20`. What you can do is have your code go through these pages from start to end, i.e. add an outer loop that loops through and adds the links from these pages to results. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to do that.